# Extending a java comparator to compare a specific class implementing the interface it compares for

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, comparator

I have a comparator like this:

```
public class XComparator implements Comparator<X>, Serializable {
}
```

that is currently used to sort a list of Y objects where Y implements X

I want to create a comparator for Y that extends XComparator so that i can compare based on a boolean data member of Y and then called super.compare.

I've tried several different approaches to this, but none seem to work at all. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why do you want to extend? Just create a new one and use the existing one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to extend `XComparator` and change the generic parameter on `Comparator` to `Y`, but you could create a `YComparator` class which just has an `XComparator` internally and delegates to it.  Something like:

```
public class YComparator implements Comparator<Y>, Serializable {
    private XComparator xComparator = new XComparator();

    @Override
    public int compare(Y y1, Y y2) {
         // compare y1.booleanData with y2.booleanData
         if (...)
             ...;

         // else otherwise:
         return xComparator.compare(y1, y2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation instead of inheritance.

Your YComparator should contain and delegate to an XComparator.